# Clearing Data in ListBox and Reload in Visual Studio 2012 C# XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I created a listbox and inserting items in the list. But, Once i get back and go to same page 
again will not clears & reloads the data. It will directly loads the data. That causes data appears two times.

Here is my coding part.

```
<ListBox x:Name="LocationList"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStretchContentStyle}"
                 Visibility="{Binding CurrentState,
                                      Converter={StaticResource StateToNormalVisibilityConverter}}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="PurchaseName" Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource LongListSelectorGroupHeaderLetterTileStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Description" Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Price"
                                                   Text="{Binding Price}"
                                                   Visibility="{Binding Purchased,
                                                                        Converter={StaticResource PurchasedBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                Content="Buy"
                                                Visibility="{Binding Purchased,
                                                                     Converter={StaticResource PurchasedBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                                Click="Buy_Location"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

How could i clear the data when i load into that particular page
???

Answer (score 1):

I guess you populate the list box on some event handler, like on `Activated`.

In that case, you should just clear the `ListBox` before adding items.

```
void MainWindow_OnActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LocationList.Items.Clear();

    // ...
    // populate LocationList here, as before
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this error by binding to a data collection... :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... />
```

... and then either:

a) Instantiate your data collection before you fill it:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>();
foreach (YourDataType data in GetDataFromDatabase())
{
    Items.Add(data);
}
```

b) Set the property explicitly each time:

```
Items = GetDataFromDatabase();
```

c) Clearing the collection property *before* adding to it:

```
Items.Clear();
foreach (YourDataType data in GetDataFromDatabase())
{
    Items.Add(data);
}
```